# Suggestions for optimising FPGA design

Tags: matlab, fpga, xilinx

I need to figure out optimisations for this FPGA design. I've got a few ideas and I'd like to know if they sound reasonable for my design. I'd also like to ask if anyone has any other ideas to improve my designs efficiency.

The design I have to optimise is an ensemble of neurons, I've included two images below.

**My current ideas**

1. Add pipeline registers between each neuron and each adder
2. 'Register the inputs and outputs' by inserting registers in-between each logic block
3. Convert the adder tree into an adder chain
4. Use time division multiplexers to share the LUT's between logic blocks

Do my current ideas for improving performance make any sense? I don't know very much about FPGA's at all so I'm not sure if my optimisations will make much of an improvement or if they even make sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Links to PDFs of my neuron and emsemble (The image quality is higher):
https://francismcnamee.com/pdfs/neuron_ensemble.pdf
https://francismcnamee.com/pdfs/single_neuron.pdf

**Ensemble of neurons (Each subsystem is a single neuron, the design of each neuron is shown below)**

[image: Ensemble of neurons]

**A single neuron**
[image: A single neuron]

Comment: 1/ It would help if I could read your pictures. The operators in the blocks are too small even when opened in a separate window.  2/ What do you want to optimise? Speed? Area?

Comment: @Oldfart Thanks for your reply, I've included links to PDF's of my designs. The PDF's are high quality so you can see everything. I'd like to optimise for either speed or area, I'd appreciate any ideas you have to achieve less area usage and/or faster speed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with *"less area usage and/or faster speed."* forget about **and**: you can optimise of area or speed. Both will not work.

> Use time division multiplexers to share the LUT's between logic blocks"

Multiplexers are also build from LUTs so you loose area before you gain some. Then the TDM needs to have a controller, the interim results need to be stored and retrieved. All and all it is not trivial and I would only do that if you are rather good at logic design. You may gain area, but you will lose speed.

> Convert the adder tree into an adder chain.

No, you don't touch the adder tree. The FPGA synthesis tool will select the optimal adder configuration for you. It will balance area against speed and come up with something much better result then you can for yourself.
In fact this applies to every part of the design:let the synthesis tool do its work. You will not be able to outperform it.

> Add pipeline registers between each neuron and each adder
>   Register the inputs and outputs' by inserting registers in-between each logic block

Sorry again but: Nope! Working with registers is not that simple.

You need to **balance** the registers. Ideally the logic delay between each pipeline stage should be the same.
Lets say you multiply takes** 10nS. The adder takes 3nS. Then you should place a pipeline stages after a set of 3 adders. The delay will be ~20nS. If you placed an pipeline stage after each adder, the total delay would be ~40nS.

Now you get to the core of speeding up a design: do you use 4 pipeline stages so you can run at 200 MHz or 2 pipeline stages and run at 100MHz? In both cases the throughput is the same.

Beware that each register stage also cost you time: you need to meet the set-up time of the register. As such the fastest design is the one *with no registers*: the data falls through at the maximum speed. But then you may need to wait a long time before you can present the next set of data.

As you may gather: balancing registers is not easy and is rather an art. The best way would be to run the design without any registers through the synthesis tool. Then run a timing analysis on it and look at the worst-case timing path. From that try to figure out where to put the register stages. But again, that is easier said then done. To me reading those timing analysis reports is easy, but for a novice they might seem all abracadabra.

Sorry if I let you hanging here but unfortunately there is no "magic trick" in these cases. Ideally you could let an experienced design play a few hours with your code and see what (s)he can do.

**<sub>The numbers I use have been made up</sub>